# How does linux generate PIDs?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, pid

I know the linux kernel has the policy to generate the PIDs wrap-around, i.e. start at `RESERVE_PIDS` until `PID_MAX_DEFAULT` sequentially. Ok my

**Question is**:

In the event that `gen_pid()` is arrivated at `PID_MAX_DEFAULT` and restarts at  `RESERVE_PIDS` and in the meantime some PIDs have been recycled, how does gen_pid() know which PIDs are used and not?